# add fields from different files

Tags: text-processing, columns, join

I have two files A and B with the same number of lines. Each of them has multiple columns.
I want to add field 6 in file A with field 3 in file B for each line. e.g.:

file A:

```
2769 RUT10EKl3fY 0 0.00483891 1352626500270 2 
2773 0XbIZqg4v7w 0 0.00360106 1352626851193 3
2777 j1tuJt5IyUw 0 0.00460544 1352627235337 4
```

file B:

```
2769 RUT10EKl3fY 1
2773 0XbIZqg4v7w 8
2777 j1tuJt5IyUw 9
```

Result (1+2, 3+8, 9+4):

```
3
11
13
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 6):

Do this:

```
$ paste A B | awk '{ print $6 + $9 }'
```

(assuming you really mean the 6th field of file A, and the 3rd of file B (6 + 3 = 9)).

Answer (score 2):

Use this reference for joinig the two files: [Question 7392204](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7392204/join-two-files-based-on-two-columns)

You can add two numbers by typing `expr 1 + 2` in bash.